# Единая БД для приложений

Tags: c#, phpbb, wordpress, mysql

Доброго времени суток!
Возник такой вопрос.
У меня есть сайт на Wordpress, у меня есть phpbb форум и у меня есть мое приложение для Win.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при регистрации на одном из ресурсов, шла автоматическая синхронизация данных БД, т.е. пользователь мог заходить как на сайт, так и в приложение, так и на форум.
Подскажите, как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Ну вы же сами в заголовке вопроса себе ответили.

Comment: "Подскажите, как лучше это реализовать?"
как бы намекает...

Comment: Можно обойтись без единой БД и замусоривания ее данными разных приложений только ради регистрации. Для этого надо держать пользователей в одной таблице БД и перебросить эту таблицу в другие БД через представление. Правда перед этим советую ознакомится с требования для представлений, которые обрабатывают запросы INSERT, DELETE и UPDATE.

Comment: Дело в том, что у wordpress, phpbb и своего приложения разные реализации регистрации/авторизации. Сначала нужно решить для себя, как будут работать эти две функции: может быть пользователи будут складываться в одну таблицу, при этом придется переделывать регистрацию/авторизацию на всех системах. Может быть наоборот проще будет добавить функцию занесения пользователей в каждую таблицу для каждой системы. А может как-то иначе.

Comment: У меня WordPress в связке с PhpBB работают уже года полтора, соединить их воедино работа не из легких. Могу рассказать как я реализовывал, но только в устной форме, по скайпу например, а то описывать все долго. Если что контакты предоставлю

Answer (score 1):

для объединения wordpress и phpBB есть специальные плагины, но и вы поймите что 100% объединения не будет, ведь это совершенно разные продукты.
Если форум ещё не очень развит то стоит его снести и пользоваться модулями форумов для wordpress.
По поводу своего приложения всё немного проще.
Для регистрации и авторизации можно использовать API Wordpress тогда получится интеграция, а все данные из вашего приложения можно хранить в доп полях пользователях или в отдельной таблице с привязкой по id пользователя. Могу помочь бесплатно (исключительно для опыта) сделать интеграцию с вашим приложением